# Use ui-validate inside a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ui-validate

It´s possible to use ui-validate inside a directive template like plunker example?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/H6v6nVobIM3EKmAVHZHa?p=preview

**template.html**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : !isValid()}">
  <label for="{{name}}" class="control-label">{{label}}</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">US$</span>
    <input type="number" 
      ng-model="ngModel" 
      ng-required="isRequired" 
      ui-validate="'$value > 0'" 
      class="form-control" 
      name="{{name}}" 
      id="{{name}}" 
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
.directive('currency', function() {
  return {
    restrict    : 'E',
    replace     : true,
    transclude  : true,
    require     : 'ngModel',
    scope       : { ngModel: '=' },
    templateUrl : 'template.html',
    link        : function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {

      scope.name = (attr.name || 'undefinedName');
      scope.label = (attr.label || 'undefinedLabel');
      scope.isRequired = (attr.required !== undefined);

      scope.isValid = function() {
        return ctrl.$valid;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Usage:**

```
<currency ng-model="foo.value" name="value" label="Value:" required></currency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Sander Elias:

> ngModel is very powerful, but it's also very picky on its surroundings. Due to the transclude and the isolate scope, ngModel does not register itself in the form.
>   but for ui-validate, it is enough to get the ng-controller itself.

To resolve basically just remove from directive the:

```
require : 'ngModel'
```

and make:

```
var ctrl = elm.find('input').data('$ngModelController');
```

A complete discussion can be seen at:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/cMgxWTM-j00